# How to start Activity from java class in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is the code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);
    Cursor cursor = myClass.getCursor();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
  }
}

public class MyClass Extends ImageButton { 

  private Context context;

  public MyClass(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public Cursor getOncreate() {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setClassName(MyClass.this,MyActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);    
  }
}
```

I want to start MyActivity from MyClass. I am getting NullPointer exception at

```
ctx.startActvity(intent);
```

Could you please suggest me how to make it correct.

Comment: Where is `ctx` defined? Shouldn't it be `context.startActivity(intent)` instead?

Comment: who is ctx? it doesn't show anywhere else in the code you posted

Comment: I have changed.but didn't work. Can you please advice me.

Comment: you should update the code in the question because I'm getting confused as to who is getCursor and getOncreate and startManagingCursor

Comment: just i have to start that application. i will take care remaining thing.

Answer (score 1):

try calling

```
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that too. It saying create startActivity. It didn't work. Please give me any alternative.

Comment: if you haven't already done so: import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;  that will fix your "create startActivity" issue

Comment: I have kept import android.app.Activity;import android.content.Intent. It was not fixed.The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MyClass. These are different activities.both are in different package but in same application.

Comment: you are right. i'll post another answer for better code delimitatin

Comment: the context you are using is null. you need to get the context (which could be your 'context' variable or what is returned from the getApplicationContext() call) and use that to launch the new activity. I can't give you much details from the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Let one of the parameters of the start activity method be of type `Context`:

```
public void methodStartActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```